the invalid "ssl" parameter in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?
i'm trying to implement a RTMP protocol with SSL/TLS for data encryption using Nginx ( 1.18.0 ) and nginx-rtmp-module, but this error happened:
nginx: [emerg] the invalid "ssl" parameter in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13

This is my nginx.conf file:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935 ssl;
        chunk_size 4096;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/rtmpssl/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/rtmpssl/rtmpprvkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;


            allow play all;
        }
    }
}

I've used the same way to implement HTTPS before and things work properly without any errors. Any suggestions will be appreciated :(
